# For IE8 - Trying to set cell spacing/padding to 0px in combination with CSS display's table_cell

Tags: css, width, css-tables, cellspacing, cellpadding

I tried to vertically align some content into div box. to achieve this I have found some CSS that works perfect. Except for you know who it doen't: IE8. When using the display attribute with the value 'table-cell', IE is creating an invisible cellpadding/cellspacing.

```
.item_box{
        display: table-cell;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        width:160px;
        height:160px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

the two lines 'padding' and 'margin' do affect only FF, Chrome, Opera. I need it to be '0' padding/spacing to preserve the main layout. Any clue how to solve this for IE?
thanks a lot

Comment: What's the element you are attempting to center inside this div?

Comment: actually "<img />" inside another "<div>". I even tried to set td.classname cellpaddind via CSS. but it didn't work. thanks and sorry for the delay.

Comment: Seems to work for me in IE8... if you post all the code maybe I can have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "invisible cellpadding/cellspacing", try experimenting with "border-collapse:collapse;" on your surrounding "display:table" container css.

Comment: OIC, this was a ghost post. I managed to miss the age of the question when I decided to post. =(

Comment: No problem. It's fine to answer old questions on Stack Overflow, since many people will stumble across the answers later via google. Thanks for posting!